# Should NSInvocation passes self as 2d indice argument?

Tags: ios, xcode, arguments, nsinvocation

I am using cocos2d for developing. I have tried to wrap a customized button class. When trying to make the button respond to the selector I assigned to it, I used NSInvocation. In it, the MyButton works like this.

```
if( target && sel ) {
            sig = [target methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
            invocation_ = nil;
            invocation_ = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
            [invocation_ setTarget:target];
            [invocation_ setSelector:sel];
            [invocation_ setArgument:&self atIndex:2];
            [invocation_ retain];
        }
```

I have passed the sel a function like this:

```
- (void)onButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

my question is: does it necessary to add this line `[invocation_ setArgument:&self atIndex:2];` in MyButton's implementation?

I have this question is because according to ios documentation here:
[NSInvocation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

it addressed that:

> Indices 0 and 1 indicate the hidden arguments self and _cmd,
> respectively; you should set these values directly with the setTarget:
> and setSelector: methods. Use indices 2 and greater for the arguments
> normally passed in a message.

it seems that self has been passed when calling setTarget, does it mean that, the &self argument is not necessary to be passed in setArgument method?

Thanks

Comment: What is `self` in this context? Where's the invocation being created?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It is MyButton, a subclass of CCNode implemented by myself. In the context, self means to regard the button it "self" as the "sender".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation just tell that the first argument (with indice 0) represent the target object (so the "self"). As the documentation explains you the first argument is set using the `setTarget:` method.

You need to keep this line of code `[invocation_ setArgument:&self atIndex:2];` to send the button's reference to the target-action pair.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that later by making some tests. Thanks for helping.